# How to find length of JSON using JSON.parse?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Json like this 
`{"0":{"parent_id":1649,"id":"1803","last_update_on":"2010-12-24 07:01:49","message":"dhb;lxd","created_by_id":"21","created_by_name":"Amol Deshpande"}}`.
So ideally i should get length as 1 considering i have only 1 value on 0th location.

what if i have a JSON like this

```
{"0":{"parent_id":1649,"id":"1803","last_update_on":"2010-12-24 07:01:49","message":"dhb;lxd","created_by_id":"21","created_by_name":"Amol Deshpande"},"1":{"parent_id":1649,"id":"1804","last_update_on":"2010-12-24 07:02:49","message":"amol","created_by_id":"21","created_by_name":"Amol Deshpande"}}
```

I am getting the value as undefined if i do alert(response.length); where response is my JSON as mentioned above

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please show the code you are using to fetch the JSON

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Objects don't have a `.length` property...not in the way you're thinking (it's `undefined`), it's *Arrays* that have that, to get a length, you need to count the keys, for example:

```
var length = 0;
for(var k in obj) if(obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) length++;
```

Or, alternatively, use [the `keys` collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) available on most browsers:

```
var length = obj.keys.length;
```

[MDN provides an implementation for browsers that *don't* already have `.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#polyfill):

```
Object.keys = Object.keys || function(o) {
    var result = [];
    for(var name in o) {
        if (o.hasOwnProperty(name))
          result.push(name);
    }
    return result;
};
```

Or, option #3, actually make your JSON an array, since those keys don't seem to mean much, like this:

```
[{"parent_id":1649,"id":"1803","last_update_on":"2010-12-24 07:01:49","message":"dhb;lxd","created_by_id":"21","created_by_name":"Amol Deshpande"},{"parent_id":1649,"id":"1804","last_update_on":"2010-12-24 07:02:49","message":"amol","created_by_id":"21","created_by_name":"Amol Deshpande"}]
```

Then you can use `.length` like you want, and still access the members by index.

Answer (score 1):

```
let _json = '{"0":{"parent_id":1649,"id":"1803","last_update_on":"2010-12-24 07:01:49","message":"dhb;lxd","created_by_id":"21","created_by_name":"Amol Deshpande"},"1":{"parent_id":1649,"id":"1804","last_update_on":"2010-12-24 07:02:49","message":"amol","created_by_id":"21","created_by_name":"Amol Deshpande"}}';
let your_json = $.parseJSON(_json);
const size = Object.keys(your_json).length;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).